# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 causing booting issues

Tags: boot

After running an upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, I am getting the following error:

```
initramfs Unable to find a medium containing live file system
```

Comment: Remove all DVD's and USB sticks. And try again please.